# Update private Wheel on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, azure, python-wheel, azure-machine-learning-service

I added a private wheel to my Azure environment via

```
    whl_url = Environment.add_private_pip_wheel(
        workspace=ws, file_path='path_to_wheel.whl', exist_ok=True)
    conda_dep.add_pip_package(whl_url)
```

When I rerun this code, it doesn't seem to update the wheel on Azure but just takes the old one. Since I'm still developing the code in the wheel, I need frequent updates, so renaming the wheel or manually increasing the version number every time is not an option.

Is there a way to tell Azure to actually update the uploaded wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue since I also constantly update the private wheel and the wheel's build number won't change by the package manager as long as the version number your package manager refers to stays the same.

You can manually change the wheel's version name, e.g. `0.4.2` to `0.4.2.1` and that would force Azure to update the environment, since Azure checks the wheel's name instead of its checksum.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can simply delete the wheel located at `whl_url` and rerun `Environment.add_private_pip_wheel`. You can find the storage account linked to your Azure ML workspace in the Azure Portal.

Comment: That is not a correct workaround, and won't work unless rebuild is forced for the same environment. that itself can break other scenarios that rely on the corresponding image due to the new set of the dependencies that will end up in the image. 
exist_ok for the same wheel means skip if exists. 
the right approach would be to manage versions properly and bump when needed. like pypi won't allow you to overwrite the version, and a new version should be pushed

Answer (score -1):

It won't update, it would skip and not error out if wheel already exists. AzureML won't replace existing whl for reproducibility purpose